# How to automatically fill Excel template

Tags: c#, .net, excel

At work each three months we have to write reports about past activities. For writing reports we have been given Excel template which contains columns to describe activity, date, time spent for the activity some combo box elements to select predefined location and some formulas.

As it takes a lot of time to rewrite all the details from personal evidence I was thinking about writing an application to write personal evidence into database and at the end of month fill the Excel template with stored data.

Does anyone know for any good resource which could be helpful for creating a solution described above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar quest.
I have found this good article
http://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html

If you are comfortable with xslt and you do not need complex Excel (with images and so on) try out SpreadsheetML, but it will generate very big files.
See my reply on this question [how to convert ms excel xml using a simple stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916571/how-to-convert-ms-excel-xml-using-a-simple-stylesheet/4935682#4935682)